# Select option base on property key in value

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<option value="abc">abc</option>
```

I know I can do `$('select').val('abc')` but what if I have something like this

```
<option value='{"name":abc,"id":123}'>abc</option>
```

How do I select `abc` base on `id`?

Comment: You need to loop through the options and set the selected property

Comment: Instead of keeping `object` as `value`, use `data-name` and `data-id` attributes..And use `$('option["data-id=123"]')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `value` is not a valid Object. `abc` should be wrapped in quotes.

The `<option>` should be

```
<option value='{"name":"abc","id":123}'>abc</option>
                       ^   ^
```

You can use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter out the `<option>` elements which are having the `id` as 123 in the `value` attribute object-like string.

Then, [`prop('selected', true)`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) can be used on the filtered `option` to set as selected option.

[**Demo:**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/g4pLeknb/)

```js
// Filtering all options in the select
$('select option').filter(function() {
    var val = $(this).val(), // Get value
        obj = {};

    // Try to parse the string to JSON
    try {
        obj = JSON.parse(val);
    } catch (e) {
        obj = {}; // Empty object if parsing fails
    }

    // Filter based on the `id` in the value
    return obj.id === 123;
}).prop('selected', true); // Set the option as selected
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="Hello">fdsafds</option>
    <option value='{"name":"abc","id":123}'>abc</option>
</select>
```

---

As [Rayon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1746830/rayon-dabre) has [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36417035/jquery-select-option-base-on-property-key-in-value/36417103#comment60449217_36417035), instead of using object as the value, I'll recommend to use HTML5 `data-*` custom attributes to store data on element.

```js
$('option[data-id="123"]').prop('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="Hello" data-name="bond" data-id="007">fdsafds</option>
    <option value="something" data-name="abc" data-id="123">abc</option>
</select>
```