# could not get property value using javascript notation

Tags: javascript

I do this

```
var routeId = $('#route option:selected').val();
console.log(routeId, routeId["id"]);
```

and I get below result

```
{"id":560,"name":"Coba wei","description":"f","is_deleted":0,"operator_id":31,"from_city_id":201,"to_city_id":46} undefined
```

I expect I can get 560, which is the second param of my console.log(), but I got undefined. Why is it so? If I do it this way here https://jsfiddle.net/hfhfug0b/, I can get the value of id.

Comment: `val()` gets you a string. You need to use `JSON.parse(str)` to make it an object like in your fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that routeId is JSON. You will need to parse it if you want to convert it to an object:

```
var routeId = JSON.parse( $('#route option:selected').val() );
console.log(routeId, routeId["id"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Anything that is read from DOM is string**. To use it as JSON, you've to parse it using [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

```
var routeId = JSON.parse($('#route option:selected').val());
```

Also, as I've recommend in [Select option base on property key in value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36417035/select-option-base-on-property-key-in-value/36417103) answer, you should consider using `data-*` attribute to store custom data on the HTML elements.

Comment: Note that `val` can return numbers or arrays too (but not any other object), though that is jQuery doing the conversion.